# Machine Learning - with sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am writing a basic stock prediction piece of code however I keep getting the following error.

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'

My code apart from this all seems to be correct and has been run to test during the process of coding. So I am pretty sure that there is no other issue causing this than a library problem with python. Does anyone know a workaround to this issue so that the project can continue? This is my code if this is any help.

```
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Getting the data
df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

#Selecting the data we want from the database
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]

#Calculating percentage changes
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100

#Refining the data even further
df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']] 

forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)


x = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
y = np.array(df['label'])
x  = preprocessing.scale(x)
y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validate.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: Hi,
If you like my answer, can you please mark it correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem is train_test_split is not inside sklearn.crossvalidate but inside sklearn.model_selection. If you want to use train_test_split you should use it like-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

For more details check out this url - 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html